# Espera infinita por resposta do servidor usando sockets em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket

Estou tentando enviar uma mensagem para a API de um servidor a fim de obter uma resposta. Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('h68.p.ctrader.com',5211)
sock.connect(server_address)

message = "8=FIX.4.4|9=87|35=0|49=theBroker.12345|56=cServer|57=QUOTE|50=BVN's Message|34=1|52=20180322-21:26:01|10=101"

sock.send(bytes(message,'utf-8'))
data = sock.recv(3)
print(data)
sock.close()
```

Porém, ao executá-lo, a mensagem é enviada para o servidor, mas no momento de receber a resposta do servidor [data = sock.recv(3)], o programa não continua. Ele fica com o cursor piscando, como se estivesse em um loop infinito. Qual a provável causa desse problema? Seria o script? A mensagem enviada ao servidor? O próprio servidor? Como solucionar o problema?

Obs: Essa mensagem está em um formato requerido pela API do servidor, que consiste em "tag"="value"|"tag"="value"|"tag"="value"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você ordena que o programa receba 3 bytes nesse socket, e eles nunca chegam.

Em um sistema para produção, você deve configurar o timeout do socket, para, se a resposta não chegar, o socket levantar uma exceção: essa exceção você trata no seu programa com o procedimento adequado: em geral fazendo algumas retentativas, com intervalos de tempo diferentes, e gerando o log e erro e mensagem apropriada de falha.

À parte disso: se no teste não chega nenhuma mensagem de volta, é por que ou o servidor não está funcionando, ou há algum erro na sua chamada - esse segundo caso é bastante mais provável. á que você tem a documentação em mãos, releia-a com atenção, e veja se existe alguma outra interpretação em como essa requisição pode ser montada - vá fazendo testes até obter uma resposta. Pode ser algo tão simples quanto incluir um caractere de avanço de linha ("\n") no final da mensagem. Pode ser que alguns campos numéricos tenham que ser mandados como bytes, em vez de strings - etc...procure exemplos d chmdas para a mesma API que funcionem.

Comment: Dando mais uma olhada na API, verifiquei que estava esquecendo de colocar um '|' no final da mensagem e que tinha que trocar '|' por '\u0001'.